# Showing has_many_through data on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I,m trying to create a access control to my system. And I have a following scenario:

An Role can have many accessrules for many workcentes.

The model is currently using the rails guide strucutre:

```
class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :accessrules
    has_many :roles, through: :accessrules 
end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :accessrules
    has_many :workspaces, through: :accessrules
end

class AccessRule < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :role 
    belongs_to :workspace
end
```

I'm trying to create a index for AccessRoles View, I don't know how to do it, I have received errors that AccessRole is not initialized and should be defined at accessrole.db

Can someone help me on how to show the joint data table (All Roles_id + Workspaces_id) in the Accessroles@index?

Comment: should be `has_many :access_rules`, I think

Comment: `AccessRule` or `AccessRole` ?

Comment: I think I found the error, the controller name was AccessRule and should be Accessrule. Since is a has many through the name does need to be Access_rules, or in this case Workspaces_roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use in migrations:

```
create_table :role_workspaces, force: true, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :role, index: true
  t.belongs_to :workspace, index: true
end
```

After this You could use (for example):

```
@role.workspaces
@workspace.roles
```

or

```
  # PUT /workspaces/1 
  def update
    @workspace = Workspace.find params[:id]
    @roles = Role.find params[:workspace][:roles]
    @workspace.roles = @roles

    respond_to do |format|
      if @workspace.update_attributes(params[:workspace])
      ...
```

Comment: The thing is that I want to put booleans for each workspace action(CRUD) in the associated table. So each role can have many workspaces with different accessrules.